# Select rows from dataframe with unique combination of values from multiple columns

Tags: r, select, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data.frame in R that is a catalog of results from baseball games for every team for a number of seasons. Some of the columns are `team`, `opponent_team`, `date`, `result`, `team_runs`, `opponent_runs`, etc.   My problem is that the because the data.frame is a combination of logs for every team, each row essentially has another row somewhere else in the data.frame that is a mirror image of that row.

For example

```
team  opponent_team  date           result team_runs opponent_runs
BAL   BOS            2010-04-05      W      5         4
```

has another row somewhere else that is

```
team  opponent_team  date           result team_runs opponent_runs
BOS   BAL            2010-04-05      L      4         5
```

I would like to write some code in `dplyr` or something similar that selects rows that have a unique ***combination*** of the `team`, `opponent_team` and `date` columns.  I stress the word combination here because order doesn't matter, I am just trying to get rid of the rows that are mirror images.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for `unique(df)`?

Comment: If we have logs from every team, and each row has a mirror image, couldn't we just take a subset of the data frame where `result == W`? This would preserve exactly 1 row for each game.

Comment: I think this is what you are asking for: 
`unique(df[,c("team","opponent_team","date")])` .    
Question is not completely clear

Comment: @ paulstey, Brilliant answer, so simple and straightforward, I never even thought about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried `distinct` function from dplyr? For your case, it can be something like

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% distinct(team, opponent_team, date)
```

Another alternative is to use `duplicated` function from base R inside `filter` function of dplyr like below.

```
filter(!duplicated(team, opponent_team, date)
```