# Creating a df of unique combinations of columns in R where order doesn't matter

Tags: r, combinations, tidyverse

I want to create a df with all of the unique combinations of three columns where the order of the value doesn't matter. In my example, I want to create a list of all the combinations of ideology groups of three people could have.

In my example, "No opinion", "Moderate", "Conservative" is the same as "Conservative" "No opinion" "Moderate" which is the same as "Moderate", "No opinion", "Conservative", etc. all of these combinations should be represented by one row.

I've seen similar [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36092076/select-rows-from-dataframe-with-unique-combination-of-values-from-multiple-colum) about using `distinct` for home and away sports teams, but I don't think this is working for this problem.

```
library(tidyverse)

political_spectrum_values = 
  factor(c("Far left",
           "Liberal",
           "Moderate", 
           "Conservative",
           "Far right",
           "No opinion"), 
           ordered = T)


political_groups_of_3 <- 
crossing(first_person = political_spectrum_values, 
         second_person = political_spectrum_values,
         third_person = political_spectrum_values)
```

I've considered making some kind of combined variable by piping into this line, but I'm not sure how to take it from here

```
unite(col = "group_composition", c(first_person, second_person, third_person), sep = "_")
```

EDIT: After working with this problem longer I've reshaped the data in a way that might make this easier

```
crossing(first_person = political_spectrum_values, 
         second_person = political_spectrum_values,
         third_person = political_spectrum_values) %>% 
  mutate(group_n = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(first_person, second_person, third_person), 
               values_to = "ideology", 
               names_to = "group") %>% 
  select(-group)
```

Comment: I'm open minded about expected output, also see my last edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A base R method is to create all the combination of `political_spectrum_values` taking 3 at a time using `expand.grid`, `sort` them by row and select unique rows.

```
df <- expand.grid(first_person = political_spectrum_values, 
                  second_person = political_spectrum_values, 
                  third_person = political_spectrum_values)

df[] <- t(apply(df, 1, sort))
unique(df)
```

If needed as a single string

```
unique(apply(df, 1, function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = "_")))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a trick you can use. Instead of starting with the names of the political leanings, start with the numbers 5^(0:5). Notice that the sum of any length-3 combination will be unique, since 3 times 5^x is less than 5^(x+1). So if you run `expand.grid` (equivalent to `crossing`) on three such vectors and take the row sums, then the positions of the unique sums will be the same as the positions of the unique combinations of names in your `crossing` result.

So you could just do this one-liner:

```
political_groups_of_3[!duplicated(rowSums(expand.grid(5^(0:5), 5^(0:5), 5^(0:5)))), ]
```

which gives:

```
#> # A tibble: 56 x 3
#>    first_person second_person third_person
#>    <ord>        <ord>         <ord>       
#>  1 Conservative Conservative  Conservative
#>  2 Conservative Conservative  Far left    
#>  3 Conservative Conservative  Far right   
#>  4 Conservative Conservative  Liberal     
#>  5 Conservative Conservative  Moderate    
#>  6 Conservative Conservative  No opinion  
#>  7 Conservative Far left      Far left    
#>  8 Conservative Far left      Far right   
#>  9 Conservative Far left      Liberal     
#> 10 Conservative Far left      Moderate    
#> # ... with 46 more rows
```

Whether this is "more elegant" or just an opaque hack is a matter of taste of course...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a two-step solution using `gtools::combinations` and `paste`.

```
library(gtools)
#Get all combinations with repeats for the political_spectrum_values in groups of 3
combs<-combinations(nlevels(political_spectrum_values),
                            3,
                            as.character(political_spectrum_values),
                            repeats = T)
#Collapse each row in a single entry and convert it into a data.frame
combs<-data.frame(group_composition = apply(combs, 
                                            1, 
                                            function(x) paste(x, collapse = "_")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer using a combination of the update and `unite`. I'll leave this open a little bit longer just incase anyone has a more elegant solution

```
crossing(first_person = political_spectrum_values, 
         second_person = political_spectrum_values,
         third_person = political_spectrum_values) %>% 
  mutate(group_n = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(first_person, second_person, third_person), 
               values_to = "ideology", 
               names_to = "group") %>% 
  select(-group) %>%
  group_by(group_n) %>% 
  arrange(ideology) %>% 
  mutate(person = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = group_n, values_from = ideology, names_from = person) %>% 
  unite(col = "group_composition", c(`1`, `2`, `3`), sep = "_") %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  distinct(group_composition)
```