# Filtering according to combination of matching data across variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataframe which includes pairs of variables from a distance matrix converted using `melt()`. It looks a bit like this:

```
 library(tibble)

 df <- tribble(~Word1, ~Word2, ~distance, ~speaker, ~session,
          "WordA", "WordX", 1.4, "JB", 1,
          "WordB", "WordY", 2.1, "JB", 1,
          "WordC", "WordZ", 4.7, "JB", 1,
          "WordX", "WordA", 0.23, "JB", 1,
          "WordY", "WordB", 2.3, "JB", 1,
          "WordZ", "WordC", 0.51, "JB", 1)
```

As in the example, each pair of word combinations occurs twice, but the variable is flipped (i.e. `WordA` and `WordX` occur together twice, each appearing once as `Word1` and once as `Word2`).

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36092076/select-rows-from-dataframe-with-unique-combination-of-values-from-multiple-colum), and have tried both suggestions:

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>% distinct(Word1, Word2, distance, speaker, session)
```

Which just reproduces the same dataframe and does not filter out the instances of matching variable combinations

And `filter(!duplicated(Word1, Word2, distance, speaker, session)`, which basically just crashes R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `filter` by the Group column after this,

```
df <-as.data.frame(df)
  
df$v <- sapply(seq(df[,1]),function(x)
         paste(sort(c(df[x,1],df[x,2])),collapse=""))
l <- data.frame(v=unique(df$v),
            Group=paste0("Group",seq(unique(df$v))))
df <- merge(df,l,by="v")[,-1]
    
df

  Word1 Word2 distance speaker session  Group
1 WordA WordX     1.40      JB       1 Group1
2 WordX WordA     0.23      JB       1 Group1
3 WordB WordY     2.10      JB       1 Group2
4 WordY WordB     2.30      JB       1 Group2
5 WordC WordZ     4.70      JB       1 Group3
6 WordZ WordC     0.51      JB       1 Group3
```